# The meaning of $\vec {\dot r}$ in the solution of a particle's movement in the space

Tags: homework-and-exercises, numerical-method

Suppose I have a charged particle $q$ with mass $m$, and an infinite long wire that lies on the $z$ axis, in which flows a constant current $I$. My ODE that describes its motion is

$$\vec {\ddot r}=\dfrac{q}{m}\vec {\dot r} \times \vec B$$
where $\vec B$ is the wire's tangential magnetic field it makes.
Is there any importance for the plot of $({\vec {\dot r(t)}})^2$ as a function of time in understanding the solution of the problem, given two initial values for $\vec r(t)$ and $\vec {\dot r}(t)$?
I am solving a numerical exercise and being asked to plot this graph. Any suggestions?

Comment: I suppose plotting $\dot r^2$ could give you a rough visual representation of how the particle's kinetic energy behaves

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the point of the exercise is to show you that $(\dot{\vec{r}})^2$ is constant.

Since magnetic fields do no work (equivalently, since the acceleration a magnetic field produces is always perpendicular to velocity), the magnitude of the velocity never changes. So, by plotting $(\dot{\vec{r}})^2$ and making sure it's constant, you can check if you made a mistake in finding the solution for $\vec{r}$.

Comment: That sound right. I must agree with you.